# string was not recognized as a valid Datetime on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, datetime, unhandled-exception

i created an app that uses DateTime.ParseExact in the following way:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(extractedFileDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

extractedFileDate is storing a string with a date, for example:
"Tue Oct 08 12:07:13 2013"

when i run my app from my computer on Windows 10 everything is running smooth, but when i try to run the same app on Windows Server 2016 i get the "string was not recognized as a valid Datetime" error massage.

the content of the date string is showing just the same value.

what can it be ?

david.

Comment: Please be aware that `ddd` does not mean "3 letter abbreviation", it only means "abbreviation", in my culture the abbreviations are followed by a full stop, and of course are written in Norwegian. Which culture is your server/application run under?

Comment: server is running he-il and my desktop is en-us

Comment: `he-il` is a right-to-left culture, that format is invalid for that culture, it uses different abbreviations. Specifically, abbreviated day in that culture for today, tuesday, is 5 letters long and written in hebrew. If you want to parse an english date, you will have to use an english compatible culture. The time right now in en-GB culture is `Tue Aug 27 13:41:14 2019`, the format you have, but for `he-IL` it is "2019 13:41:31 27 יום ג אוג" (and Stack Overflow gets confused about the right-to-left mix here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(extractedFileDate, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: @DavidGidony Just make sure other systems don't use in `he-IL` again by also sending using Invariant Culture. Otherwise another mismatch would occur.

Answer (score 2):

A culture has `DateTimeInfo` which contains specific information about how to parse the string. In example, the names of the days of the week of months of the year.

Your format string contains `ddd MMM` and your string to parse `Tue Oct` so this might be the problem when the server has another culture configured.

You are using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Try to use your desktop culture when parsing the string.

Update: In your comment you ask how to support multiple cultures. In the case of data transfer or storage the best method is to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when (de)serializing `DateTime`. This culture is independent of the local settings. When presenting to the user (in a GUI) use the default (user's configured) culture.

Comment: how can i make my code support multiple cultures ? my desktop shows en-us and the server shows he-il

Comment: You would first have to decide what "support multiple cultures" *mean*. If you have an english language formatted date, you will need to use an english compatible culture.